# Is there program that would let me alter the colors and brightness levels of my screen in depth?

Tags: windows, display

While I do have simple settings that enable me to change overall saturation, contrast, brightness, and gamma, I'm wondering if there are programs that allow me to change them in depth.

I just feel like the light tones on web pages are super bright, even if I do use a program to dim down my screen, but if I dim it down too much, then the dark parts of the screen will be hard to see. And no, reducing the overall settings mentioned above doesn't get me my desired result.

I'm wondering if there is a program that lets me alter contrast in depth, preferably with the precision of a curve adjuster you find in photo editors. I very specifically want to alter my light tones without altering my mid tones, or dark tones. Ofc, it doesn't have to actually be a curve adjuster, but something akin to the detail it offers.

An example of what I'm trying to achieve would to make the light tones POP less, and fade ever so slightly more into the mid-tones while the dark values remain the same.

[image]

It would be a total bonus if it's a program that allows me to alter individual color intensity/hue/brightness, akin to photoshop's selective color.

[image]

The only program I can think of that comes close to this is reshade, but this only works for specific programs. It doesn't alter the overall display.

Comment: I want one of those for my computer output to TV too. Damn Rec709 gamma curves ;))